# Which figure is homeomorphic to the figure only constructed by all the edges of a cube?

Tags: general-topology, nonlinear-dynamics

[image]Can someone transform a cube which only has its edges to a figure that is homeomorphic to it?

What is the genus of this figure?

Comment: Are you thinking of the cube edges like little tubes, so that the figure is a surface, or are you thinking of it as a 1-dimensional union of edges and vertices? Normally, I would assume you meant the latter, but your reference to "genus" makes me think the former.

Comment: Any figure is homeomorphic to itself, but presumably this answer won't satisfy you. What additional properties do you want the other figure to have?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Even though not a surface, there is a concept of genus of a graph, skip to the graph section in the wiki article on genus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)

Comment: @GregMartin  I mean the former one. Can this be converted into a figure only has 3 holes.

Comment: If we are thinking of it as a surface and not a 1 dimensional graph, the genus is $5$. One way to figure this out is to notice there is a spanning tree with 7 edges. You can think of a small neighborhood of this as a sphere. Then, each of the additional 5 edges you attach adds an extra handle, which each add one to the genus. In fact, if you open this picture out in the plane so it is two nested squares connected by lines, you can actually count the 5 holes.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip do you want to post that as an answer?